# Make two elements equal height, one with a vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make two sibling div elements the same height. The of them has an overflow-y and a scrollbar with variable height content. The main div has content that is also variable height depending on dynamic content and browser width. The main content div should show all its content. The left scrolling panel should be equal height to the main content and no matter the browser width or height of content, hence the scrolling bar.

Previously, I would have used jQuery, detect window width change and adjust accordingly. But I am trying to do it in a React app.. so ideally it would be CSS only. Is this possible?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="panel-with-scroll">
       <div class="panel-inner">
        <p>panel with scroll</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
}

.panel-with-scroll {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: pink;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

An example of the mark-up and css is here at JSBIN:

https://jsbin.com/yivonew/edit?html,css,output

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/0rnbw71w/

Comment: That just fixes the height of the whole thing. I'm trying to keep the height of the content div dynamic depending on content, and have the scrolling panel adjust itself to match the height.

Comment: Flexbox cannot do that. Try absolute positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34194042/3597276

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that to work make the `panel-inner` absolute positioned and set `overflow-y: scroll` on it.

With that you can make the `content` dynamically sized by its content and have the panel always equal height, and scroll when its content does not fit

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
}
.panel {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
.panel-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="panel">
       <div class="panel-inner">
        <p>panel with scroll</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
         <p>..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content panel</p>
      <p>content panel</p>
      <p>content panel</p>
      <p>content panel</p>
      <p>content panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height in the parent elemrnt, not in the child elements:

```
.parent {
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
display: flex;
}

.panel-with-scroll {
width: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background: pink;
}

.content {
background: yellow;
width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: That works, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to keep the height of the content div dynamic depending on content, and have the scrolling panel adjust itself to match the height.

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent {
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
display: flex;
}

.panel-with-scroll {
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
background: pink;
}

.content {
background: yellow;
width: 400px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Try this. I think you might have to use javascript if you want the height of the div with a scroll to be dependent on the height of the div with dynamic content. Otherwise, you can set their heights to both 100%.