# Is it possible to make equal width flexbox items to prefer minimum width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 buttons. As you can see they all have equal width and together they fill the whole container. Can I make flex items to prefer minimum width but still remain equal width without specifying particular dimensions? Any help appreciated.

[image]

**Clarification:** As you can see the longest labeled button has some space that can be cut off. Can I make it minimum width and the rest of the buttons same width.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "prefer minimum width but still remain equal width". That seems contradictory.

Comment: I'll try to clarify. I mean columns of equal minimum width. As you can see the longest labeled button has some space that can be cut off. Can I make it minimum width and the rest of the buttons same width. Like this :)

Comment: The flex equal width feature (`flex-grow: 1`) is based on the free space in the container, not the length of one item. If you want the items to be smaller, so they tightly wrap the longest content and remain equal width, reduce the size of the container. Otherwise, this isn't something CSS can do. You'll need a script.

Comment: Here's a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34194042/3597276

Comment: Thank you very much guys. You made it clear.