# Aspect ratio property not working in horizontal flexbox, why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this very simple flexbox layout with some text and a background image element beside it. The background image element to the right needs to automatically keep the same height as the text element as well as an aspect ratio of 1/1, like so:

**Expected:**
[image]

But the aspect ratio property is ignored. The height of the `#image` element is set to the height of the flexbox like I want it (since the flexbox by default sets `align-items: stretch`). But the width stays at 0, despite the aspect ratio property, which should set the width to the same as the height.

Interestingly, if the flexbox is set to `flex-direction: column` it does work as expected.

Why isn't aspect ratio correctly applied in a row flexbox and how do I fix it?

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, gray);
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">
    <h3>A headline</h3>
    And some text below it<br>
    Element to the right should be a square
  </div>
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

aspect-ratio will work when one of width and height will be define then second property width/height will adjust according to aspect-ratio.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#image {
  height: 120px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, gray);
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">
    <h3>A headline</h3>
    And some text below it<br>
    Element to the right should be a square
  </div>
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the height needs to be dynamically set to be the same height as the text element always. And I've seen other working examples where neither height or width were fixed. But in this case it apparently can't use the height implicitly set by the flexbox container.

Comment: @Illiou Well, If you want to set the height same as height of text element, use the unit ch. For example, in your case add `height : 1ch` to `#image{....}` in your CSS file. I would like to ask you to edit your question with what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Using `ch` would set the height to something smaller than a line of text, not the height of the whole text container. My question already mentioned that I need it to be dynamic, but I have clarified the wording and added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bug. Maybe not. Can't really tell at the moment with limited review.

But seems to work fine in Grid.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

#image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, gray);
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">
    <h3>A headline</h3>
    And some text below it<br>
    Element to the right should be a square
  </div>
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your image is much larger than the text per the OP question notes.  I think that is an easy fix here though.

Comment: It's a potential solution that the OP may be able to tweak. It also introduces Grid as an alternative to Flex.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but when I previously tried this with grid I couldn't get the image to be the same height as the text, which is my main goal. If there is an easy fix, please share :)

Comment: Here's a potential JavaScript solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54317997/3597276

Comment: Thanks, although I am still looking for a CSS solution here.

Answer (score -1):

This feels like a bit of a hack, but here's a potential solution to the OP's problem based on @Michael Benjamin's answer using grid instead of flex. To keep the image from growing we can give the grid column that contains it a width of `.01fr` (any really small value should do), and then to expand the image to exactly the height of the text, we can give it a height of `100%`. That works because the image has an aspect ratio of `1 / 1` but since it has a width of `.01fr` the text is taller by default and determines the height of the grid. One thing that might be a problem is that `fit-content` on the container element means that the container width is the the width of the text + `.01fr`, so with this solution the image is actually overflowing the container

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr .01fr;
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

#image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, gray);
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">
    <h3>A headline</h3>
    And some text below it<br>
    Element to the right should be a square
  </div>
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work on both chromium and webkit browsers. Also, if you know what you want the width of the container to be then `fit-content` might not be necessary