# Flex item won't shrink with overflow - it still remains as high as content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I want one of the children of the `display: flex;` to adjust the height to the others. If the content in this children is bigger than the other children's, then `overflow: scroll;` should be done to this content.

**In other words:**
I expect the middle div (yellow background) from the following code to adjust its height to the others div's with overflow of `.tabl`.

I know that the question is like many others. I have already read many threads and I still have not managed to solve the problem. I apologize for this post, but I do not have the strength to solve it.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 .tabl {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <p>Some element one</p>
    <p>Some element two</p>
    <p>Some element three</p>
    <p>Some element four</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Element</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tabl">
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <button class="btn">Some button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child3">
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will probably help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48943233/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want one of the children of the display: flex; to adjust the height to the others.

Suppose you want the *green section* (`child3`) to have the largest height:

- make sure you have `align-items: stretch` (its the default, so don't override it) - this ensures that each *row flex child* stretches to the maximum height flex child.
- wrap the contents of the other sections (`child1` and `child2`) into an *absolutely positioned* element.
- make this wrapper element a *column flexbox* to get the overflow right on the *yellow section*.

See demo below:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /*align-items: baseline;*/
}

.child1 {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 .tabl {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto; /* changed to auto */
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 { /* ADDED */
  position: relative;
}

.child-wrap { /* ADDED */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  <div class="child-wrap">
    <p>Some element one</p>
    <p>Some element two</p>
    <p>Some element three</p>
    <p>Some element four</p></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child2">
  <div class="child-wrap">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Element</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tabl">
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <button class="btn">Some button</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child3">
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Suppose you want *either* of the left or right sections to have the maximum height - in that case use the above *absolute positioning* only for the *middle yellow element* - see demo below where the highest of the *left or right elements* define the height of the whole `parent` *wrapper* :

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /*align-items: baseline;*/
}

.child1 {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 .tabl {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto; /* changed to auto */
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 { /* ADDED */
  position: relative;
}

.child-wrap { /* ADDED */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <p>Some element one</p>
    <p>Some element two</p>
    <p>Some element three</p>
    <p>Some element four</p>
    <p>Some element two</p>
    <p>Some element three</p>
    <p>Some element four</p>
  </div>

  <div class="child2">
    <div class="child-wrap">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Element</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tabl">
        <p>Some element one</p>
        <p>Some element two</p>
        <p>Some element three</p>
        <p>Some element four</p>
        <p>Some element one</p>
        <p>Some element two</p>
        <p>Some element three</p>
        <p>Some element four</p>
        <p>Some element one</p>
        <p>Some element two</p>
        <p>Some element three</p>
        <p>Some element four</p>
        <p>Some element one</p>
        <p>Some element two</p>
        <p>Some element three</p>
        <p>Some element four</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <button class="btn">Some button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child3">
    <p>Some element one</p>
    <p>Some element two</p>
    <p>Some element three</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the last div (green) will not be the highest (it will not necessarily be the highest). Sometimes the first div (red) can be the highest - then the middle (yellow) height should also be adjusted to the highest one.

Comment: so use absolute positioning *only* for the *yellow middle element* - I guess that will work out in that case... try it out - see the updated answer...

Comment: Ok, it's a very good idea :) I was hoping to use only flexbox for this purpose, but this solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Overflow** in this context means nothing without defining a *height* after which the content should *flow over*. The problem (*or benefit, in most cases*) with flex is the boxes will grow to match the "biggest" content, or rather flex (hence the name). You'll probably need Javascript for this, or you'll need to define a max-height on the children.

Below is an example of your code with a `max-height` applied to children;

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.child2 .tabl {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child1, .child2, .child3{
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <p>Some element one</p>
    <p>Some element two</p>
    <p>Some element three</p>
    <p>Some element four</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Element</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tabl">
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <button class="btn">Some button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child3">
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
      <p>Some element one</p>
      <p>Some element two</p>
      <p>Some element three</p>
      <p>Some element four</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The view must be... flexible. :) I can not set the maximum height in any place. Sometimes, the elements on the left or right may be higher than the middle ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the desired height of your flex children in advance, using the `max-height` property is the cleanest solution provided natively by Flexbox, as @Lewis suggested.

Should you need more fine-grained control, consider using the CSS Grid layout module. If you swap out your existing code with the snippet below and apply it to your markup, you can see a minimalist reproduction of the layout you're trying to achieve.

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
}

.parent > * {
  border: 2px solid black; // added for clarity
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.child2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your .parent an heigh of for example
     max-height: 150px;