# Prevent image from expanding beyond other elements of flex row

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to build a card-based layout, with an image taking up the left-hand half of each card. If I use a `div` with a `background-image`, the image takes up exactly half the width, and expands to exactly the height of the content on the right-hand side of the card.

However, if I instead use an `img` element (with `object-fit: cover`), the image never crops vertically when the card is too short, but instead only horizontally when the card is too tall. How can I tell the image not to cause the card to stretch, reproducing the behaviour of the `div`'s background image?

As an example, the third and fourth cards are what I am trying to achieve, but with an image tag for semantic reasons.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1em;
}

article > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

article > div:first-child {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

article > aside {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900" />
    <aside>
      <h2>img taller than the text</h2>
      <p>
        Here the image extends beyond the text, which I do not want.
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900" />
    <aside>
      <h2>img shorter than the text</h2>
      <p>
        With enough text, the image is the right height, with both the <kbd>img</kbd> tag and the background image.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ut turpis est. Maecenas vehicula tempor purus, non laoreet turpis aliquet sit amet. Sed pellentesque augue at risus dignissim porttitor. Curabitur aliquam justo ut ante imperdiet lobortis. Aenean sit amet dui eros. Pellentesque dictum imperdiet ex in condimentum. Proin imperdiet eros a sapien egestas, quis auctor arcu laoreet. In interdum at ligula sit amet ornare. Mauris sed feugiat eros. Vestibulum in eros auctor, iaculis neque eu, tincidunt neque. Curabitur eget ligula ac tortor viverra cursus non id nunc. Morbi vestibulum ligula felis, id aliquam metus placerat at. In sed urna bibendum, volutpat ipsum et, placerat dui. 
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
  <article>
  <div style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900)">
  </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>background image</h2>
      <p>
        With very little text, the background image is cropped to take up little height, which is what I'm trying to achieve with an image tag.
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
  <article>
  <div style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900)">
  </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>background image</h2>
      <p>
        With enough text, the image is the right height, with both the <kbd>img</kbd> tag and the background image.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ut turpis est. Maecenas vehicula tempor purus, non laoreet turpis aliquet sit amet. Sed pellentesque augue at risus dignissim porttitor. Curabitur aliquam justo ut ante imperdiet lobortis. Aenean sit amet dui eros. Pellentesque dictum imperdiet ex in condimentum. Proin imperdiet eros a sapien egestas, quis auctor arcu laoreet. In interdum at ligula sit amet ornare. Mauris sed feugiat eros. Vestibulum in eros auctor, iaculis neque eu, tincidunt neque. Curabitur eget ligula ac tortor viverra cursus non id nunc. Morbi vestibulum ligula felis, id aliquam metus placerat at. In sed urna bibendum, volutpat ipsum et, placerat dui. 
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: you have almost done it. You added an extra div to use the background, simply add your image inside that div instead of add it as background

Comment: @TemaniAfif would you be able to provide an example? I'm still finding very similar results when I put the `img` in a `div`.

Comment: From further experimenting, I can position the image absolutely (width and height to 100%), with this parent div positioned relatively, but is this really the most elegant way of doing so?

Comment: *most elegant* is opinion based, for me it works and it's a solution.

Comment: @TemaniAfif please could you post the code that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make the image out of the flow using `position:absolute` so only the text content will define the height:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}

article {
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; not needed sine one element is in-flow */
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1em;
  position:relative;
}

article > img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


article > aside {
  padding: 1em;
  width:50%;
  margin-left:auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900" />
    <aside>
      <h2>img taller than the text</h2>
      <p>
        Here the image extends beyond the text, which I do not want.
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900" />
    <aside>
      <h2>img shorter than the text</h2>
      <p>
        With enough text, the image is the right height, with both the <kbd>img</kbd> tag and the background image.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ut turpis est. Maecenas vehicula tempor purus, non laoreet turpis aliquet sit amet. Sed pellentesque augue at risus dignissim porttitor. Curabitur aliquam justo ut ante imperdiet lobortis. Aenean sit amet dui eros. Pellentesque dictum imperdiet ex in condimentum. Proin imperdiet eros a sapien egestas, quis auctor arcu laoreet. In interdum at ligula sit amet ornare. Mauris sed feugiat eros. Vestibulum in eros auctor, iaculis neque eu, tincidunt neque. Curabitur eget ligula ac tortor viverra cursus non id nunc. Morbi vestibulum ligula felis, id aliquam metus placerat at. In sed urna bibendum, volutpat ipsum et, placerat dui. 
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
```

Similar question: [How can you set the height of an outer div to always be equal to a particular inner div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48943233/8620333)

Answer (score 2):

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1em;
}

article > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

article > div:first-child {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

article > aside {
  padding: 1em;
}
.img-container{
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.img-container div{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.img-container img{
      object-fit: cover;     
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
   <div class="img-container">
   <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>img taller than the text</h2>
      <p>
        Here the image extends beyond the text, which I do not want.
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
  <article>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900" />
    </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>img shorter than the text</h2>
      <p>
        With enough text, the image is the right height, with both the <kbd>img</kbd> tag and the background image.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ut turpis est. Maecenas vehicula tempor purus, non laoreet turpis aliquet sit amet. Sed pellentesque augue at risus dignissim porttitor. Curabitur aliquam justo ut ante imperdiet lobortis. Aenean sit amet dui eros. Pellentesque dictum imperdiet ex in condimentum. Proin imperdiet eros a sapien egestas, quis auctor arcu laoreet. In interdum at ligula sit amet ornare. Mauris sed feugiat eros. Vestibulum in eros auctor, iaculis neque eu, tincidunt neque. Curabitur eget ligula ac tortor viverra cursus non id nunc. Morbi vestibulum ligula felis, id aliquam metus placerat at. In sed urna bibendum, volutpat ipsum et, placerat dui. 
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
  <article>
  <div style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900)">
  </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>background image</h2>
      <p>
        With very little text, the background image is cropped to take up little height, which is what I'm trying to achieve with an image tag.
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
  <article>
  <div style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/411/1000/900)">
  </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>background image</h2>
      <p>
        With enough text, the image is the right height, with both the <kbd>img</kbd> tag and the background image.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ut turpis est. Maecenas vehicula tempor purus, non laoreet turpis aliquet sit amet. Sed pellentesque augue at risus dignissim porttitor. Curabitur aliquam justo ut ante imperdiet lobortis. Aenean sit amet dui eros. Pellentesque dictum imperdiet ex in condimentum. Proin imperdiet eros a sapien egestas, quis auctor arcu laoreet. In interdum at ligula sit amet ornare. Mauris sed feugiat eros. Vestibulum in eros auctor, iaculis neque eu, tincidunt neque. Curabitur eget ligula ac tortor viverra cursus non id nunc. Morbi vestibulum ligula felis, id aliquam metus placerat at. In sed urna bibendum, volutpat ipsum et, placerat dui. 
      </p>
    </aside>
  </article>
</main>
```

Use **object-fit: cover; width:100%; height:100%;**. You need to specify width and height with "object-fit: cover" to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Mileesh, this doesn't seem to answer the question: the first image still extends beyond the text.

Comment: In which browser you are testing?. It is working fine in Chrome  74.0.3729.169

Comment: @CharlieHarding Fixed the issue. Please see the snippet

Comment: Thanks Mileesh. I've accepted @TemaniAfif's solution, as he posted a working answer first, and it seems to be the same idea, but thank you!