# CSS Grid use specific item height as max row height

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to prevent the sidebar height from exceeding the content height.
The "area" will contain an image of any height so its height is not fixed or known in advance.

```js
function toggleTabsContent() {
 const display = document.querySelector('.content').style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
   document.querySelector('.content').style.display = "block";
  } else {
   document.querySelector('.content').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "tabs area"
    "footer footer";
}

.tabs {
  grid-area: tabs;
  background: #FF9800;
}

.area {
  grid-area: area;
  height: 200px;
  background: #673AB7;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #607D8B;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleTabsContent()">Make tabs taller/shorter</button>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="content" style="display: none"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="area"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yd2rojp/11/)

Comment: " want to show scrollbar when the "tabs" height is more than the "area" height." do you mean on right of sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `height:0;min-height:100%;` on the `tabs` element. This will make sure the height of the element will not contribute on the size of its track then by adding `min-height:100%` you force it to use the height of the track defined by other elements:

```js
function toggleTabsContent() {
 const display = document.querySelector('.content').style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
   document.querySelector('.content').style.display = "block";
  } else {
   document.querySelector('.content').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "tabs area"
    "footer footer";
}

.tabs {
  grid-area: tabs;
  background: #FF9800;
  height:0;
  min-height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.area {
  grid-area: area;
  height: 200px;
  background: #673AB7;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #607D8B;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleTabsContent()">Make tabs taller/shorter</button>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="content" style="display: none"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="area"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Related question: [How can you set the height of an outer div to always be equal to a particular inner div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48943233/8620333)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`Display: flex;` allows for a lot of flexibility - in fact it's purpose is exactly to flex the height or width to the required dimensions per the content inside of it.

Based on your question, this is exactly what you need.

I've separated your footer from the grid, in order to separate statically sized elements, from those you wish to flex.

Next I've added a min-width to your area, to avoid it collapsing completely. However if you want this functionality, you can remove this. i.e. if you want that when there is no image it doesn't appear, you can remove this.

Lastly, the `display: flex;` and `flex-flow: row nowrap;` allows the sizing to flex, and for elements within the grid (now named "flex") to be placed next to each other with the same dimensions and they won't wrap to the next line to accommodate the sizing changes.

```js
function toggleTabsContent() {
  const display = document.querySelector('.content').style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.querySelector('.content').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.content').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.tabs {
  background: #FF9800;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.area {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #673AB7;
}

.footer {
  background: #607D8B;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleTabsContent()">Make tabs taller/shorter</button>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="content" style="display: none"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="area"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max-height of `tabs` to be the height of `area`

```
.tabs {
  grid-area: tabs;
  background: #FF9800;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

I added lot of `H1` elements and it worked the way you wanted it.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pja3vk2e/22/)

Comment: The area height is not fixed as I mentioned, so I can't use `400px` in this case

Comment: @UnLoCo if you don't know the area height why not use min-height? This way the sidebar will always show something. Or you can set sidebar min-height...

Answer (score 0):

You should go the flex route, but if the only content in `.tabs` is an image, you can set it as a background-image and let it automatically fill the area with `background-size: cover`.

```js
document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener('change', changeAreaHeight);

function changeAreaHeight(event) {
  let sliderValue = event.target.value;
  document.querySelector('.area').style.height = sliderValue + 'px';
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "tabs area"
    "footer footer";
}

.tabs {
  grid-area: tabs;
  background: #FF9800;
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/167/100/300.jpg'); /* NEW */
  background-size: cover; /* NEW */
}

.area {
  grid-area: area;
  height: 200px;
  background: #673AB7;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #607D8B;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider" min="50" value="200" max="800" />
<label>Change height on .area</label>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="content" style="display: none"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="area"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```