# Set elements height to follow sibling height in display flex row

Tags: html, css, height, display

I have the following structure in my project:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="super-child">
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="A"><div>
    </div>
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="B"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I have the following restrictions with this structure:

- *container* class must be display flex and be on column mode
- *super-child* class must be display flex and be on row mode
- *uneditable* class does cannot receive any styling at all, only that they have height and width 100%

What i'm trying to do is style this structure so that class *A* has a dominating height of over *B*, that is, if *A* height grows, *B* will have more height to match *A's*, if *A* is smaller, *B* will have the same height as *A's*

I've tried to set grow and shrink values in the class *A* and *B*. I can also change the displays to grid, but in my case is not preferred to.

Is there a way to make this dependence of height without using javascript to style the elements?

**[UPDATE]**

Found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943233/how-can-you-set-the-height-of-an-outer-div-to-always-be-equal-to-a-particular-in). The solution was to use the following style for all children of super-child, except the first.

```
height: 0;
min-height: 100%;
```

This works due the fact that this conjunction of height definition can be understood as "have no height, just expand enough not pushing the boundaries"

Comment: can you add your CSS and clarify if the 2 children are side by side or on top of each others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I would use grid for this, not flex *and pay attention to the closing tag too :)* , flex will require a bit of js to update heights :

example in a column *since in a row should not be an issue*

```css
.super-child {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
.super-child > .uneditable {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="super-child">
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="A">A <br> AA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="B"> B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="super-child">
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="A">A </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="B"> B<br> BB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... side by side :

```css
.super-child {
  display: flex;
}
.super-child > .uneditable {
  border: solid;
  flex:1;
  
  
  /* demo purpose to resize heights */
  overflow-y:scroll;
  resize:vertical
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="super-child">
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="A">A <br> AA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="B"> B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="super-child">
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="A">A </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uneditable">
      <div class="B"> B<br> BB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that they need to be on a row display, side by side, not on the A above B

Comment: @MuriloMaestro then side by side should not be a trouble, I added a snippet to the answer to demonstrate that it is a flex native behavior . If it goes wrong for you, we might be missing some of your CSS (or you did not fix the div  closing tag mistype `<div class="A"><div>` from your code that should be `<div class="A"></div>` )  ;)