# Set height of div based on previous div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I have a for loop that creates product cards using Bootstrap. I want to add an additional card after where the user can click through to view all products in that category. I want that additional card to always been the same size and it's previous card. I have tried several JavaScript solutions from Google but can't get it to work.

My code is as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<!-- Disposable Vape Section -->
<section>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center mt-5">
                <h2 class="logo-font">Shop Disposables - Over 100 flavours available</h2>
                <hr class="w-50 mb-5">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="product-container col-10 offset-1">
                <div class="row mt-1">
                    {% for product in products %}
                    {% if product.category.name == 'disposable_vape' %}
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="card h-100 border-0">
                            {% if product.image %}
                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}"
                                    alt="{{ product.name }}">
                            </a>
                            {% else %}
                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png"
                                    alt="{{ product.name }}">
                            </a>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                <p class="mb-0">{{ product.name }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer bg-white pt-0 border-0 text-left">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <p class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold">£{{ product.price }}</p>
                                        {% if product.category %}
                                        <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                                            <a class="text-muted"
                                                href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ product.category.name }}">
                                                <i class="fas fa-tag mr-1"></i>{{ product.category.friendly_name }}
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if product.rating %}
                                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i>{{ product.rating }} /
                                            5</small>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <small class="text-muted">No Rating</small>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                                        <small class="ml-3">
                                            <a href="{% url 'edit_product' product.id %}">Edit</a> |
                                            <a class="text-danger"
                                                href="{% url 'delete_product' product.id %}">Delete</a>
                                        </small>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:1 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-sm-none mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-none d-xl-block mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="card h-100 border-0">
                            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?filter=category&category=disposable_vape"
                                class="stretched-link"></a>
                            <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                <div class="d-flex center">
                                    <div class="btn btn-prod-black">
                                        <a href="{% url 'products' %}?filter=category&category=disposable_vape"
                                            class=""></a>
                                        <span class="text-uppercase">Shop
                                            All Disposables
                                            <span class="icon">
                                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btt-button shadow-sm rounded-0 border border-black">
        <a class="btt-link d-flex h-100">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-black mx-auto my-auto"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Nicotine Salts Section -->
<section>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center mt-5">
                <h2 class="logo-font">Shop Nicotine Salts</h2>
                <hr class="w-50 mb-5">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="product-container col-10 offset-1">
                <div class="row mt-1">
                    {% for product in products %}
                    {% if product.category.name == 'liquid_nic_salts' %}
                    <div class="home-card col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="card h-100 border-0">
                            {% if product.image %}
                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}"
                                    alt="{{ product.name }}">
                            </a>
                            {% else %}
                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png"
                                    alt="{{ product.name }}">
                            </a>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                <p class="mb-0">{{ product.name }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer bg-white pt-0 border-0 text-left">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <p class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold">£{{ product.price }}</p>
                                        {% if product.category %}
                                        <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                                            <a class="text-muted"
                                                href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ product.category.name }}">
                                                <i class="fas fa-tag mr-1"></i>{{ product.category.friendly_name }}
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if product.rating %}
                                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i>{{ product.rating }} /
                                            5</small>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <small class="text-muted">No Rating</small>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                                        <small class="ml-3">
                                            <a href="{% url 'edit_product' product.id %}">Edit</a> |
                                            <a class="text-danger"
                                                href="{% url 'delete_product' product.id %}">Delete</a>
                                        </small>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:1 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-sm-none mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                    <div class="col-12 d-none d-xl-block mb-5">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="home-card-extra card h-100 border-0">
                            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?filter=category&category=liquid_nic_salts"
                                class="stretched-link"></a>
                            <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                <div class="d-flex center">
                                    <div class="btn btn-prod-black">
                                        <a href="{% url 'products' %}?filter=category&category=liquid_nic_salts"
                                            class=""></a>
                                        <span class="text-uppercase">Shop
                                            All Nicotine Salts
                                            <span class="icon">
                                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btt-button shadow-sm rounded-0 border border-black">
        <a class="btt-link d-flex h-100">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-black mx-auto my-auto"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>


{% endblock %}

{% block postloadjs %}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#home-card-extra").height($("#home-card").height());
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can set a specific height of all cards

Comment: Thanks but the card height is dynamic based on content so I want the final card to just automatically to the same size as the previous card

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48943583/8620333

Comment: Thanks Temani. However, my css for these cards is set by Bootstrap CSS. So they would be even more complicated than a JS solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a nifty little JS function. All I had to do was add an inner div class of equalHeight and then postload the following js:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  (function() {
    equalHeight(false);
  })();

window.onresize = function() {
  equalHeight(true);
}

function equalHeight(resize) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("equalHeight"),
    allHeights = [],
    i = 0;
  if (resize === true) {
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.height = 'auto';
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var elementHeight = elements[i].clientHeight;
    allHeights.push(elementHeight);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.height = Math.max.apply(Math, allHeights) + 'px';
    if (resize === false) {
      elements[i].className = elements[i].className + " show";
    }
  }
} <
/script>
```