# Make flex item siblings the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this simple example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.logo {}

.text {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/103x121.png/ff0" alt="test logo"></div>
  <div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

I need image to get same height as sibling div on right side not vv, i.e. shrink image to actual text height and keep aspect ratio.

Answer (score 5):

How is one sibling supposed to know the height of another sibling? That's outside the scope of CSS. You'll need a script for that.

But both siblings can share equal height if they refer to the height of their parent.

This may not be what you want, but here's one potential solution:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 50px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/103x121.png/ff0" alt="test logo"></div>
  <div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Also see: [One flex/grid item sets the size limit for siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34194042/3597276)

Answer (score 2):

Use the same `font-size` value for the image `height`, but can't be `%` units.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.logo img {
  height: 3em;
  width: auto;
}

.text {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/103x121.png/ff0" alt="test logo"></div>
  <div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `display:flex` in the parent container generally the child elements can be sized by specifying a fixed height of the parent container and setting the child elements accordingly with a `flex-direction` default being `row` as @Michael_B suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 50px;
}
.logo {
    object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  font-size: 300%;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/103x121.png/ff0" alt="test logo"></div>
  <div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not set the left item to the height of the right item, but to the height of the container.