# Is there a way to dictate which column in a css-grid dictates the height of the row?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a css-grid which includes an svg. I would like the height of this svg to be scaled by the content of another column.

I have looked at height: min-content & max-content but the svg will set its width to the max available therefore it will define the height of the row itself. What would be perfect would be a property like "grid-height-self: content"

Comment: There is no specific property that will permiit this but the solution for flexbox applies here also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-item-sets-the-height-limit-for-siblings