# Auto adjust/crop the height of an image inside a bootstrap col, to be equal to height of another col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a boostrap row containing 2 columns, the left column contains some text, the right column contains an image.

I want to set the max-height of the right column to be equal to the height of the left column - which may change due to resizing of the window (has a min-height property).

I want to crop the image which I believe can be achieved using "object-fit:cover" within css

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="row" id="test-row">
    <div class="col-2" id="test-left">
        Some random text
    </div>
    <div class="col-10" id="test-right">
        <img src="img_source" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have looked online and at other posts but all seem to be based around the column not needing to be cropped or downsized.

Comment: Related? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-item-sets-the-height-limit-for-siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you are willing to make your image a background image.

```
<style>
     #bg-image {
        background-image: url('example.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
     }
</style>
<div class="row" id="test-row">
    <div class="col-2" id="test-left">
            Some random text
    </div>
    <div class="col-10" id="test-right">
        <div id="bg-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise use a javascript window resize event to set the height.