# Prevent column expanding height of container

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have a two-col layout built with Vuetify, where the left column contains media of varying aspect ratio, and the right column contains a playlist. When the playlist gets too long, it expands the height of the container leaving an empty area under the media.

I'm trying to have it so if the right column has too much content it scrolls, without expanding the container. I've tried setting a max height, but as the aspect ratio of the media can vary, the maximum height isn't know, meaning it can get cut off too early.

```
<v-card dark>
  <v-row no-gutters class="playlist-container">
    <v-col cols="8" class="pa-0">
      <!-- media element, could be image or video of any aspect ratio -->
      <img src="https://placehold.it/1400x700">
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="4" class="pa-0">
      <!-- playlist container -->
      <v-layout fill-height column justify-space-between>

        <!-- playlist items -->
        <v-list class="pa-0" class="playlist-items">
          <v-subheader>Category title</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item two-line link v-for="(video, idx) in items" :key="idx">
            <v-list-item-avatar class="ma-2 ml-0 font-weight-bold">
              {{ idx + 1 }}
            </v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>{{ video.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>example &bull; 1k stats</v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-action-text class="mr-2">
              6:39
            </v-list-item-action-text>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>

        <!-- bottom link -->
        <v-list class="pa-0">
          <v-divider />
          <v-list-item two-line link>
            <v-list-item-avatar class="mr-4">
              <v-icon size="32" color="primary">play_circle_filled</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>Lorem ipsum</v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>Bottom text</v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-layout>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-card>
```

Here is a minimal demo: https://codepen.io/benlewisjsy/pen/ExjjGeq

Comment: Related if not dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-item-sets-the-height-limit-for-siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it by adding a class to the playlist items `v-list`, with the below:

```
.playlist-container .playlist-items {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current height of the right-hand column as a computed property using `document.getElementById` and `element.offsetHeight`, then set the playlist container:

```
<v-col class="pa-0 overflow-y-auto" :style="{'max-height': `${height}px`}">
```

where `height` is the computed height.