# How to stop a flexbox child from expanding the parent container in the secondary flex direction?

Tags: css, flexbox

How to stop a specific flexbox child from expanding the parent container in the secondary flex direction?

```css
.my-component {
  display: flex;
}

.parent-wrapper {
  align-items: start;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent-big {
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child { background-color: #FFCC99; }
.child-big { background-color: #99FFCC; }
```

```html
<div class="my-component">
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    Some other parent wrapper
  </div>
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="parent-big">
      <div class="child-big">
        Some Random Big Child 1
      </div>
      <div class="child-big">
        Some Random Big Child 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        Child 3
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        Child 4
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        Child 5
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        Child 6
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        Child 7
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        Child 8
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I want `.parent-wrapper` to not take into account of `.parent`, while also allowing it to grow based on other children. How to stop `.parent` from expanding `.parent-wrapper`?

Got

[image]

I need

[image]

Comment: `width: 0;
    min-width: 100%;` to parent container

Comment: What is the width of `.parent-wrapper` supposed to be?

Comment: @Michael_B max(200px, max width of all its children except `.parent`)

Comment: Not sure it can work with pure CSS. Here's some background: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34194042/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B TemaniAfif 's solution works; same as the answer to the question linked. It wasn't just for image, that hack works for other elements as well