# Force image in flex container to match the height of other flex elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two side by side flex elements with fixed width, one with text and one with an image. How can I force the size of the image in the right container to dynamically match the height of the text in the left container, while preserving the aspect ratio and avoiding cropping?

```css
.flexbox {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.left {
    width: 60%;
}

.right {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200" class="placeholder" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probable duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-grid-item-sets-the-size-limit-for-siblings

Answer (score 3):

Set your image as position absolute inside a relative parent that has `flex:1`

```css
.flexbox {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200" class="placeholder" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also set an height and min-height as a max-width just in case it get distorded.

[`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) & [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) can also help avoid distorsion and resize the picture, At screen it is quiet similar to background-position/background-size but handles a single image at once.

```css
.flexbox {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

img {
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  background:yellow;
   /* object-fit/object-position are also options here to avoid image being distorded */
}

.bis img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position:top 0 left 0;
}

.flexbox {
  transition: 0.25s
}

.flexbox:hover {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
hover the flex boxes to increase width and font-size and see img behavior.
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/221/200/400" class="placeholder" />
  </div>
</div>
You may also clip that img vi <code>object-fit</code> and <code>object-position</code>.
<div class="flexbox bis">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/221/200/400" class="placeholder" />
  </div>
</div>
```