# CSS grid second column childs height based on first column height without js

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to make something like collage where I have 3 images. First is large on left side and two others smaller which placed in right side one above the other. **Key feature is that the first image can have different height**

[image]

I've used a css grid, but I don't know, how to make row (or content) height in second column to be based on first column, where I have element on 2 rows height.

I've created a fiddle for better understanding https://jsfiddle.net/x0jd2Lcf/, but result is not what I want:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.container img:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/246x354" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/164x236" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/164x236" />
</div>
```

Edit: first image (large, in left column) should not change its size

[image]

Comment: Don't think you can do that with your current structure. If you wrap the 2nd/3rd images in a separate element you might - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-grid-item-sets-the-size-limit-for-siblings

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap every `img` element in a container, you can use `object-fit` to fill up the containers entire space without distorting your image.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

img{
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img_container">
  <img src="http://sfwallpaper.com/images/random-image-14.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="img_container">
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/random-multicolored-spheres-computer-generated-abstract-form-of-large-picture-id1295274245?b=1&k=20&m=1295274245&s=170667a&w=0&h=4t-XT7aI_o42rGO207GPGAt9fayT6D-2kw9INeMYOgo=" />
  </div>
  <div class="img_container">
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/random-multicolored-spheres-computer-generated-abstract-form-of-large-picture-id1295274245?b=1&k=20&m=1295274245&s=170667a&w=0&h=4t-XT7aI_o42rGO207GPGAt9fayT6D-2kw9INeMYOgo=" />
  </div>
</div>
```