# Element's height should depend on other element while keeping min-height and show an optional scrollbar in CSS

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, scrollbar, css-grid

I need help to style the blue container in following design. The blue container should have a min-height of 400px, an optional vertical scrollbar and automatically grow if the green container is taller than the red and blue container combined.

[image: Examples with small or tall image]

- If the green container is small (left example), the blue container should be 400px tall and show an optional scrollbar.
- If the green container is tall (right example), the blue container should grow, so the red and blue container combined are the same height as the green container. If necessary, a scrollbar should be shown.

It's important that the blue container should have a min-height of 400px and only grow to fit the height of the green container. It should not grow if the inner content itself is tall but should just show a scrollbar then.

If this isn't possible with pure CSS, please let me know, then I'll try it with JavaScript. However, I would prefer CSS because the content of all three containers (red, blue, green) are completely variable and can change dynamically.

---

I tried to implement it with grid and flex but wasn't able to meet all my requirements. Especially if there was a lot of content in the blue container, either the container itself was just 400px tall or was 100% tall without showing any scrollbar. To start, here is a template you can use. Even though it grows correctly, it doesn't shrink the blue container to min-height nor does it show the optional scrollbar if you add more lines to it:

```
<style>
  .content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "red green green"
    "blue green green"
  }

  .red {
    grid-area: red;
    background-color: lightsalmon;
  }

  .blue {
    grid-area: blue;
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .green {
    grid-area: green;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  }
</style>

<div class="content">
  <div class="red">variable content</div>
  <div class="blue">
    <div>min-height 400px</div>
    <div>auto scrollbar</div>
    <div>auto grow if image is taller</div>
    <div>line</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="green">image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-grid-item-sets-the-size-limit-for-siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a vertical flex direction for the left column, such that the blue area has a `flex-basis` of `400px` to fulfil the minimum height stipulation. The `flex-grow: 1` then enables the blue area to fill any extra empty space if the parent is taller.

The parent maintains the same height of the green area due to the implicit `align-items: stretch` value of its own parent horizontal flex layout. `align-self: start` overrides the `align-items: stretch` on the `green` element so that it can shrink smaller than the left side.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

.red {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1 0 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  flex-basis: 67%;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="red">variable content</div>
    <div class="blue">
      <div>min-height 400px</div>
      <div>auto scrollbar</div>
      <div>auto grow if image is taller</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="green">image</div>
</div>
```