# CSS Grid - possible to prevent adjacent sibling expanding height?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to prevent the adjacent column in a CSS grid row from expanding to the same height as its sibling when it is being toggled to an expanded state? Ideally I don't have to split the HTML markup into separate left and right columns for this, but I'm not sure if it's possible to avoid it.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qmLo5y2f/

```css
.product-data {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.product-data .item-wrap {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #E2DFCC;
}

.product-data .item-content {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-data">
<details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">
      Details </summary>
    <div class="item-content">

      <div class="description">
        <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. Sed nisl elit, aliquet et dapibus sit amet, tristique eget ipsum. Donec sed elit orci. Integer sodales arcu nisi, at euismod dui tincidunt at. Aenean non elit vitae arcu scelerisque interdum eget ut orci. Integer fermentum nibh urna, id volutpat nulla lobortis sit amet. Nulla ac aliquet quam, vitae condimentum ipsum. Vestibulum et tortor tellus.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">
      Details </summary>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. Sed nisl elit, aliquet et dapibus sit amet, tristique eget ipsum. Donec sed elit orci. Integer sodales arcu nisi, at euismod dui tincidunt at. Aenean non elit vitae arcu scelerisque interdum eget ut orci. Integer fermentum nibh urna, id volutpat nulla lobortis sit amet. Nulla ac aliquet quam, vitae condimentum ipsum. Vestibulum et tortor tellus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">
      Details </summary>
    <div class="item-content">

      <div class="description">
        <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. Sed nisl elit, aliquet et dapibus sit amet, tristique eget ipsum. Donec sed elit orci. Integer sodales arcu nisi, at euismod dui tincidunt at. Aenean non elit vitae arcu scelerisque interdum eget ut orci. Integer fermentum nibh urna, id volutpat nulla lobortis sit amet. Nulla ac aliquet quam, vitae condimentum ipsum. Vestibulum et tortor tellus.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">
      Title </summary>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. Sed nisl elit, aliquet et dapibus sit amet, tristique eget ipsum. Donec sed elit orci. Integer sodales arcu nisi, at euismod dui tincidunt at. Aenean non elit vitae arcu scelerisque interdum eget ut orci. Integer fermentum nibh urna, id volutpat nulla lobortis sit amet. Nulla ac aliquet quam, vitae condimentum ipsum. Vestibulum et tortor tellus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </details> 
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-grid-item-sets-the-size-limit-for-siblings

Comment: I am editing your code by adding the product-data class div to better showcase the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update the `.product-data .item-wrap` CSS to `margin-bottom: auto;` to keep the other item in the row from growing in height when a column in the row is expanded.

This will remove the spacing between the rows, but you can get that back by using `margin-top: 20px;` instead

Comment: It is better to set align-items: baseline on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You may have put a margin bottom on for some other reason but it seems like you should instead have `grid-row-gap: 1.25em;` on the grid then you can put the bottom margin as `auto` instead which will size each to the content.

- I set the font size to most browsers default 16px then use em as a more modern approach
- Changed the bottom margin `margin-bottom: auto;`
- set that row gap to the same as what the bottom margin was before but put it on the grid instead `grid-row-gap: 1.25em;`
- Adjusted the second elements content to illustrate that difference when both are expanded
- Fixed the broken markup

Note this is not truly the "sibling" but the content of the sibling perhaps.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.product-data {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 3.125em;
  grid-row-gap: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 1.875em;
}

.product-data .item-wrap {
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid #E2DFCC;
}

.product-data .item-content {
  padding: 1.25em 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-data">
  <details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">Details</summary>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="description">
        <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis
          magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. Sed nisl elit, aliquet et dapibus sit amet, tristique eget ipsum. Donec sed elit orci. Integer sodales arcu nisi, at euismod dui tincidunt at. Aenean non elit vitae
          arcu scelerisque interdum eget ut orci. Integer fermentum nibh urna, id volutpat nulla lobortis sit amet. Nulla ac aliquet quam, vitae condimentum ipsum. Vestibulum et tortor tellus.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">Details</summary>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis
        magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">Details</summary>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="description">
        <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis
          magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. Sed nisl elit, aliquet et dapibus sit amet, tristique eget ipsum. Donec sed elit orci. Integer sodales arcu nisi, at euismod dui tincidunt at. Aenean non elit vitae
          arcu scelerisque interdum eget ut orci. Integer fermentum nibh urna, id volutpat nulla lobortis sit amet. Nulla ac aliquet quam, vitae condimentum ipsum. Vestibulum et tortor tellus.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="item-wrap">
    <summary class="item-label">Title</summary>
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat mauris id lacus lacinia lacinia. Cras arcu sem, tincidunt eget purus eget, scelerisque eleifend nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae eros ullamcorper, lobortis
        magna a, cursus velit. Sed sodales tellus lorem, a ultrices libero molestie vel. Sed nisl elit, aliquet et dapibus sit amet, tristique eget ipsum. Donec sed elit orci. Integer sodales arcu nisi, at euismod dui tincidunt at. Aenean non elit vitae
        arcu scelerisque interdum eget ut orci. Integer fermentum nibh urna, id volutpat nulla lobortis sit amet. Nulla ac aliquet quam, vitae condimentum ipsum. Vestibulum et tortor tellus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>

</div>
```