# Adequate block deployment is not working html/css

Tags: html, css

*Adequate block deployment is not working html/css. Blocks do not work properly. There are blocks, and if you click on one block, the next block expands, this happens on the tablet version, what to do?* **Example: in the picture, when one block is expanded, another block is expanded behind it.I want to make sure that when you click on one block, the second does not open**[[image]

```css
.team {
  width: 688px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container_team {
  width: 744px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.input {
  display: none;
}

.input:checked~.p {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  clip-path: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.input:checked+.item_label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.h3 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: center;
}

.im {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.team {
  max-width: 743px;
}

.team h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  line-height: 25px;
}

.team picture {
  width: 330px;
  height: 203px;
}

.team .le {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.team .lea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.team .pZ {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.team .zp {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.team label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.team label::after {
  content: '+';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.team input:checked~label::after {
  transform: rotateZ(315deg);
}

.team .men {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.team .buzne {
  width: 300px;
}

.team .tele {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #F5FFD9;
}

.team .Ar {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .Di {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .ro {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .te {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .su {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .container_team .p {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1px;
  max-height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clip-path: inset(100%);
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

.team picture {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

.team picture img {
  width: 330px;
  height: 203px;
}

.h2 {
  margin-left: 190px;
}

.team .container_team .input:checked~.p {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  clip-path: none;
}

.Ar>.team input:checked {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="team">
  <h2 class="h2">Команда розробників</h2>
  <div class="container_team">
    <div class="men">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="" id="checks1">
      <label for="checks1">
                <h3 class="h3">Менеджер проекту</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">Менеджер проекту розподіляє завдання між командою, планує хід роботи, мотивує команду, контролює процес та координує спільні дії. Також він несе відповідальність за тайм-менеджмент, управління ризиками та дії у разі непередбачених ситуацій. Основний
        обов’язок і відповідальність PM – довести ідею замовника до реалізації у встановлений термін, використовуючи наявні ресурси. В рамках цієї задачі PM’у необхідно створити план розробки, організувати команду, налаштувати процес роботи над проектом,
        забезпечити зворотній зв’язок між командами та замовником, усувати перешкоди для команд, контролювати якість і виконання термінів. Його основне завдання полягає в управлінні проектом. Як і бізнес-аналітик, менеджер проекту також може бути включений
        у комунікацію з клієнтом, проте головним завданням PM є робота безпосередньо з командою розробників програмного забезпечення. Середній вік в Україні- 30 років. Вирізняються високим рівнем освіти (тільки 6% не мають вищої освіти). Зарплата 1700-2500$.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buzne">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="" id="checks2">
      <label for="checks2">
                <h3 class="h3">Бізнес аналітик</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">Це фахівець, який досліджує проблему замовника, шукає рішення і оформлює його концепцію в формі вимог, на які надалі будуть орієнтуватися розробники при створенні продукту. Середньому українському бізнес-аналітику 28 років, він має зарплату $ 1300-2500
        і досвід роботи 3 роки.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tele">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks3">
      <label for="checks3">
                <h3 class="h3">Team Lead</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">Це IT-фахівець, який керує своєю командою розробників, володіє технічною стороною, бере участь у роботі над архітектурою проекту, займається рев'ю коду, а також розробкою деяких складних завдань на проекті. За статистикою ДНЗ, середній вік українських
        тімлідів – 28 років, середній досвід роботи – 6,5 років, середня зарплата – $2800.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Ar">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checks4">
      <label for="checks4">
                <h3 class="h3">Архітектор ПЗ</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">
        Приймає рішення щодо внутрішнього устрою і зовнішніх інтерфейсів програмного комплексу з урахуванням проектних вимог і наявних ресурсів.Головна задача архітектора – пошук оптимальних (простих, зручних, дешевих) рішень, які будуть максимально відповідати
        потребам замовника і можливостям команди. За статистикою ДОУ, середньому українському архітектору 30 років, він має 9-річний досвід роботи і отримує $ 4000.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Di">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks5">
      <label class="label_comamnd" for="checks5">
                <h3 class="h3">Дизайнер</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">Спеціаліст, який займається проектуванням інтерфейсів користувача. В середньому українському дизайнеру – 26 років, він має досвід роботи від півроку (джуніор) до 5 років (сеньйор) і отримує зарплату $ 1000-200</p>
    </div>
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width:1280px)" srcset="img/team1x.png 1x,img/team2x.png 2x,img/team3x.png 3x">
      <img class="im" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Проект">
    </picture>
    <div class="ro">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks6">
      <label for="checks6">
                <h3 class="h3">Розробник</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">Фахівець, який пише вихідний код програм і в кінцевому результаті створює технології. Програмісти також мають різні галузі експертизи, вони пишуть різними мовами та працюють з різними платформами. Тому і існує така “різноманітність” розробників,
        залучених до одного проекту. На одному проекті переважно завжди є як мінімум два програмісти- перший, який займається back-end розробкою та інший, відповідальний за front-end. Існує два напрямки програмування - системне та прикладне. Системні
        програмісти мають справу з ОС, інтерфейсами баз даних, мережами. Прикладні – з сайтами, програмним забезпеченням, програмами, редакторами, соцмережами, іграми тощо. Програміст розробляє програми за допомогою математичних алгоритмів. Перед початком
        роботи йому необхідно скласти алгоритм або знайти оптимальний спосіб вирішення конкретного завдання. В середньому українському програмісту 27 років, його зарплата в середньому дорівнює $ 1500-2500, а досвід роботи становить 4,5 років.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="te">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks7">
      <label for="checks7">
                <h3 class="h3">Тестувальник</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">Фахівець, необхідний для кожного процесу розробки для забезпечення високої якості продукту. Вони тестують його, проходять через усі додатки та визначають баги та помилки з подальшим наданням звіту команді розробки, яка проводить їх виправлення За
        даними ДОУ, середньому українському QA-інженеру 26 років. Він має досвід роботи від півроку (джуніор) до 5 років (сеньйор) і отримує зарплату $ 600-2700.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="su">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks8">
      <label for="checks8">
                <h3 class="h3">Support</h3>
            </label>
      <p class="p">Ключове завдання support-фахівця (або Customer Support Representative) — відповідати на запитання і допомагати клієнтам у телефонному режимі, поштою або у чаті. Решта завдань залежать від процесів у конкретній компанії.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I still haven't found out the problem I looked on the Internet, no solution!

I'm studying html/css/js at a computer school and they haven't solved this problem yet. I hope you can help us)

Comment: I can't see anything here that would clarify the issue more, than when you first asked that same question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/78163822/1427878

Comment: Your screenshot appears to show two blocks _next to_ each other. If have no idea what you even mean, when you describe the problem as _"another block is expanded behind it"_ ...?

Comment: Could you say what you want to happen to the block next to the one that has been opened. If you don’t want it to look as though it’s expanded, what should things look like? E.g. do you want the selected block to flow over the elements beneath so nothing moves? Perhaps a sketch of what it should look like will help us.

Comment: You can have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78148778/css-grid-possible-to-prevent-adjacent-sibling-expanding-height), it will surely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change a little your HTML as below (taking out the image and moving also the .buz class at fifth position inside .container_team). You can use then the columns:2; layout for your .container_team and display:inline-block for its children (named here ib) .

```css
.team {
  width: 688px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container_team {
  columns: 2;
  width: 744px;
}

.container_team > .ib{
  display: inline-block;
}


.input {
  display: none;
}

.input:checked~.p {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  clip-path: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.input:checked+.item_label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.h3 {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: center;
}

.im {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.team {
  max-width: 743px;
}

.team h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  line-height: 25px;
}

.team picture {
  width: 330px;
  height: 203px;
}

.team .le {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.team .lea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.team .pZ {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.team .zp {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.team label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.team label::after {
  content: '+';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.team input:checked~label::after {
  transform: rotateZ(315deg);
}

.team .men {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.team .buzne {
  width: 300px;
}

.team .tele {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #F5FFD9;
}

.team .Ar {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .Di {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .ro {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .te {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .su {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team .container_team .p {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1px;
  max-height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clip-path: inset(100%);
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

.team picture {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

.team picture img {
  width: 330px;
  height: 203px;
}

.h2 {
  margin-left: 190px;
}

.team .container_team .input:checked~.p {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  clip-path: none;
}

.Ar>.team input:checked {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
  <section class="team">
    <h2 class="h2">Команда розробників</h2>
    <div class="container_team">
        <div class="men ib">
            <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="" id="checks1">
            <label for="checks1">
                <h3 class="h3">Менеджер проекту</h3>
            </label>
            <p class="p">Менеджер проекту розподіляє завдання між командою, планує хід роботи, мотивує команду, контролює процес та координує спільні дії. Також він несе відповідальність за тайм-менеджмент, управління ризиками та дії у разі непередбачених ситуацій. Основний обов’язок і відповідальність PM – довести ідею замовника до реалізації у встановлений термін, використовуючи наявні ресурси. В рамках цієї задачі PM’у необхідно створити план розробки, організувати команду, налаштувати процес роботи над проектом, забезпечити зворотній зв’язок між командами та замовником, усувати перешкоди для команд, контролювати якість і виконання термінів. Його основне завдання полягає в управлінні проектом. Як і бізнес-аналітик, менеджер проекту також може бути включений у комунікацію з клієнтом, проте головним завданням PM є робота безпосередньо з командою розробників програмного забезпечення. Середній вік в Україні- 30 років. Вирізняються високим рівнем освіти (тільки 6% не мають вищої освіти). Зарплата 1700-2500$.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tele ib">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks3">
            <label for="checks3">
                <h3 class="h3">Team Lead</h3>
            </label>
            <p class="p">Це IT-фахівець, який керує своєю командою розробників, володіє технічною стороною, бере участь у роботі над архітектурою проекту, займається рев'ю коду, а також розробкою деяких складних завдань на проекті. За статистикою ДНЗ, середній вік українських тімлідів – 28 років, середній досвід роботи – 6,5 років, середня зарплата – $2800.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Ar ib">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checks4">
            <label for="checks4">
                <h3 class="h3">Архітектор ПЗ</h3>
            </label>
            <p class="p">
Приймає рішення щодо внутрішнього устрою і зовнішніх інтерфейсів програмного комплексу з урахуванням проектних вимог і наявних ресурсів.Головна задача архітектора – пошук оптимальних (простих, зручних, дешевих) рішень, які будуть максимально відповідати потребам замовника і можливостям команди. За статистикою ДОУ, середньому українському архітектору 30 років, він має 9-річний досвід роботи і отримує $ 4000.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Di ib">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks5">
            <label class="label_comamnd" for="checks5">
                <h3 class="h3">Дизайнер</h3>
            </label>
            <p class="p">Спеціаліст, який займається проектуванням інтерфейсів користувача. В середньому українському дизайнеру – 26 років, він має досвід роботи від півроку (джуніор) до 5 років (сеньйор) і отримує зарплату $ 1000-200</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buzne ib">
          <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="" id="checks2">
          <label for="checks2">
              <h3 class="h3">Бізнес аналітик</h3>
          </label>
          <p class="p">Це фахівець, який досліджує проблему замовника, шукає рішення і оформлює його концепцію в формі вимог, на які надалі будуть орієнтуватися розробники при створенні продукту. Середньому українському бізнес-аналітику 28 років, він має зарплату $ 1300-2500 і досвід роботи 3 роки.</p>
      </div>
        <div class="ro ib">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks6">
            <label for="checks6">
                <h3 class="h3">Розробник</h3>
            </label>
            <p class="p">Фахівець, який пише вихідний код програм і в кінцевому результаті створює технології. Програмісти також мають різні галузі експертизи, вони пишуть різними мовами та працюють з різними платформами. Тому і існує така “різноманітність” розробників, залучених до одного проекту. На одному проекті переважно завжди є як мінімум два програмісти- перший, який займається back-end розробкою та інший, відповідальний за front-end. Існує два напрямки програмування - системне та прикладне. Системні програмісти мають справу з ОС, інтерфейсами баз даних, мережами. Прикладні – з сайтами, програмним забезпеченням, програмами, редакторами, соцмережами, іграми тощо. Програміст розробляє програми за допомогою математичних алгоритмів. Перед початком роботи йому необхідно скласти алгоритм або знайти оптимальний спосіб вирішення конкретного завдання. В середньому українському програмісту 27 років, його зарплата в середньому дорівнює $ 1500-2500, а досвід роботи становить 4,5 років.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="te ib">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks7">
            <label for="checks7">
                <h3 class="h3">Тестувальник</h3>
            </label>
            <p class="p">Фахівець, необхідний для кожного процесу розробки для забезпечення високої якості продукту. Вони тестують його, проходять через усі додатки та визначають баги та помилки з подальшим наданням звіту команді розробки, яка проводить їх виправлення За даними ДОУ, середньому українському QA-інженеру 26 років. Він має досвід роботи від півроку (джуніор) до 5 років (сеньйор) і отримує зарплату $ 600-2700.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="su ib">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checks8">
            <label for="checks8">
                <h3 class="h3">Support</h3>
            </label>
            <p class="p">Ключове завдання support-фахівця (або Customer Support Representative) — відповідати на запитання і допомагати клієнтам у телефонному режимі, поштою або у чаті. Решта завдань залежать від процесів у конкретній компанії.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width:1280px)" srcset="https://picsum.photos/200 1x,https://picsum.photos/200 2x,https://picsum.photos/200 3x">
      <img class="im" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Проект">
  </picture>
</section>
```